# "Class ... does not have a main method" NetBeans 10.0

Tags: java, netbeans, ubuntu-20.04

I'm new in Java, I've been trying to run this code:

```java
package Pruebas;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Hola Mundo");
    }
}
```

It builds fine but when I try to run it it gives me a `"No main classes found"` error. I've tried to go to project>properties>run, and in main class I've written Pruebas.Main (packagename.mainfilename), but I get the same error.

I've also tried to run the main file only, and I get this error `"Pruebas.Main does not have a main method"`. Also I created a new project and create the main class automatically but I get the same errors, I don't know what to do.
I'm using `NetBeans 10.0` in `Ubuntu 20.04`.

Thank for your time.

Comment: Is your file name alright? Please check your file name is Main.java or not? The filename should match exactly with the class name.

Comment: I would guess a problem with the project configuration. If you right-click on your Main.java source file and select "Run File" what happens?

Comment: I tried that but gives me a "Pruebas. Main does not have a Main method" error. The file name is Main. java as the clases name